# Update statement for one column from sourcedb.table.column to my current column. Error: Could not be bound

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been having trouble with a simple update statement wherein I would update my new database and populating some columns with the old database. Here is the current query I have

```
USE PHARMA
UPDATE item 
SET item_uom = POSDB.dbo.Items.uom
WHERE item_name = POSDB.dbo.items.item_desc
```

The query fails and the message  sql gives me is this:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "POSDB.dbo.items.item_desc" could not be bound.
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to use a join to bind to the table in a different database (in this case, `from POSDB.dbo.Items` should be enough).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this might be what you want:

```
USE PHARMA
UPDATE item 
SET item_uom = pos.uom
FROM item i
INNER JOIN POSDB.dbo.Items pos 
ON i.item_name = pos.item_desc
```

Comment: Thank you very much! You were of great help